# Is there any way for an application, running at background, to know that user provided Incorrect password on the lock screen?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to build an application in android
which will be spanned from the background 
when a user will provide incorrect password 
5 times.

Is there any way I can get the user has typed incorrect password or an unlock pattern on the android lock screen?

Comment: Sir that is not your playground, you can't access another application without that app giving you the chance. so **NO** you can only know when the user unlocks the screen

Comment: I'm not accessing another application. Read my question again!

Comment: I'm accessing it's default unlocking system!